# Or statement in Python 3 variables

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple python program that detects a constanant at the beginning of a word and moves it to the end (like piglatin). Can I make a variable like

```
conts = "b" or "c"
```

Then if/else to detect if the word starts with b or c. Is this possible?

Comment: No, it's not...

Comment: You cannot do it like this, but you can have it as an array and then check whether the starting char is in the array

Comment: You said "constanant", did you mean to say "consonant"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that however an easy alternative is to use the `in` operator.

```
conts = {'a', 'b'}
my_string = 'apples'
if my_string[0] in conts:
    print(my_string[1:] + my_string[0])
else:
    print(my_string)
```

Comment: Use a set instead of a list for things like this